# Typesetting journal names and abbreviations

Tags: macros, bibtex

I am confused. What is the proper / accepted way of using the journal macros in bibliography? I have found about 3 different sources, and each of them has an incomplete set of the journal macros that I need:

- the aastex package
- jabbrv.sty (which is not maintained as far as I can see from the webpage)
- standalone files like http://cdsads.u-strasbg.fr/abs_doc/aas_macros.sty

Is there a universal way to use these macros in a bibliography? All I want is a reference file which as all abbreviations for journals, so that I can use them without having to constantly edit the bibliography manually.

Comment: what do you mean by "the journal macros"? Each journal that accepts latex will have specific instructions and usually a specific class file to use.

Comment: Sorry, I added more explanations in edit.

Comment: Normally the bibliography would be generated by bibtex so all you would be editing a .bib file rather than dealing directly with tex files for the references. It is still very hard to understand your question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! There is not really a proper or accepted way of using journal abbreviations or LaTeX macros for such abbreviations. Specific journals or conferences can force you to use certain predefined abbreviations, at least for journals that they publish themselves, other journals or conferences may require you to write all names in full, yet other journals are not so strict. In any case, when you publish in a journal, your paper is usually checked and edited by the publisher to comply to standards, so you don't necessarily have to do it 'right' when you submit.

Comment: Practically, if you want to use abbreviations and you know which ones you need, then it is easy to just make your own macro file (for example by extending the AAS file in your question) and use those macros in your bibliography.